How to Configure Angular Build to Skip Rebuilding the Entire TypeScript Code in Angular When Only Files under Assets or Public Folders Are Updated?
I’m working on reducing build time for my Angular project, especially in cases where only files in src/assets or src/public have changed. In these cases, the Angular build process (ng build) still seems to fully rebuild the application, which can be time-consuming. I’m exploring ways to configure Angular’s build tool to recognize changes only in specific folders and skip a full rebuild if possible.
My goal is to:
Detect when changes are limited to only src/assets or src/public.
Skip the full build process in those cases and, if possible, directly update only the modified files in the final dist folder.
Research So Far
I’ve looked through the Angular CLI documentation but couldn’t find any specific flags or options that would allow the build tool to selectively skip a full build based on changes in certain folders. I've considered using file-watching tools or partial rebuild configurations but haven't found anything that directly meets this need.
Question
Is there any way to configure Angular’s build system (ng build) to skip a full rebuild when only static assets change? Are there flags, plugins, or other configurations that allow for more granular build control?
If there is no solution that is native to angular, can it be done with CI/CD pipeline configuration?

Why would a build run multiple times is the main question, it should happen only during deployments, there is no way the assets will change when the build is running, unless you do --watch which you do on local machine, that too its an incremental build, which does not take a long time in general

Native Angular does not support this. There is a cache, however only dependencies are stored in the cache, not the built application. You can check out Nx remote cache.

Angular doesn't have such configuration options. However, if you are looking to optimize your build size and reduce build time, then you can explore build optimization: https://angular.dev/reference/configs/workspace-config#optimization-configuration

older angular versions don't have build cache yet.
